# Reading HTML content from a UIWebView

Tags: html, iphone, uiwebview

Is it possible to read the raw HTML content of a web page that has been loaded into a `UIWebView`?

If not, is there another way to pull raw HTML content from a web page in the iPhone SDK (such as an equivalent of the .NET `WebClient::openRead`)?

Answer (score 216, accepted):

The second question is actually easier to answer. Look at the [`stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1497360-stringwithcontentsofurl?language=objc) method of NSString - it lets you pass in a URL as an instance of NSURL (which can easily be instantiated from NSString) and returns a string with the complete contents of the page at that URL. For example:

```
NSString *googleString = @"http://www.google.com";
NSURL *googleURL = [NSURL URLWithString:googleString];
NSError *error;
NSString *googlePage = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:googleURL 
                                                encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                   error:&error];
```

After running this code, `googlePage` will contain the HTML for www.google.com, and `error` will contain any errors encountered in the fetch. (You should check the contents of `error` after the fetch.)

Going the other way (from a UIWebView) is a bit trickier, but is basically the same concept. You'll have to pull the [request](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview/1617972-request?language=objc) from the view, then do the fetch as before:

```
NSURL *requestURL = [[yourWebView request] URL];
NSError *error;
NSString *page = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:requestURL 
                                          encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                             error:&error];
```

**EDIT:** Both these methods take a performance hit, however, since they do the request twice. You can get around this by grabbing the content from a currently-loaded UIWebView using its `stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:` method, as such:

```
NSString *html = [yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: 
                                         @"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

This will grab the current HTML contents of the view using the Document Object Model, parse the JavaScript, then give it to you as an NSString* of HTML.

Another way is to do your request programmatically first, then load the UIWebView from what you requested. Let's say you take the second example above, where you have `NSString *page` as the result of a call to `stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:`. You can then push that string into the web view using `loadHTMLString:baseURL:`, assuming you also held on to the NSURL you requested:

```
[yourWebView loadHTMLString:page baseURL:requestURL];
```

I'm not sure, however, if this will run JavaScript found in the page you load (the method name, `loadHTMLString`, is somewhat ambiguous, and the docs don't say much about it).

For more info:

- [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview?language=objc) class reference
- [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring?language=objc) class reference
- [NSURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl?language=objc) class reference

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the great answer.  I presume both methods result in the page being loaded twice, which may have a performance impact.  Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: As a matter of fact, there are :) Edited answer.

Comment: Yes, [yourWebView loadHTMLString:page baseURL:requestURL]; will run the Javascript in the page. I've used this api with Google maps.

Comment: NSString *html = [yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: 
                                         @"document.body.innerHTML"];    it looses the formatting, what should i do?

Comment: `NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];` has been a lifesaver for me several times now.  It seems to return from the document as much as possible.

Comment: @Hanuman This might help you:

    NSString *head = [yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.head.innerHTML"];



NSString *body = [yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.innerHTML"];

NSString *totalPage = append both strings.

Answer (score 92):

if you want to extract the contents of an already-loaded UIWebView, -stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString. For example:

```
NSString  *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

Comment: The question I have is what happens if the content happens to be a JSON string or even a raw string without a body tag?

Comment: This is not a healthy solution! All the javascript code and header info is lost this way.

Answer (score 44):

To get the whole HTML raw data (with `<head>` and `<body>`):

```
NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];
```

Answer (score 30):

Note that the NSString stringWithContentsOfURL will report a totally different user-agent string than the UIWebView making the same request. So if your server is user-agent aware, and sending back different html depending on who is asking for it, you may not get correct results this way.

Also note that the `@"document.body.innerHTML"` mentioned above will only display what is in the body tag. If you use `@"document.all[0].innerHTML"` you will get both head and body. Which is still not the complete contents of the UIWebView, since it will not get back the !doctype or html tags, but it is a lot closer.

Comment: Theoretically, you *could* get the doctype by requesting it from the server. It's likely that the doctype won't change based on useragent.

Answer (score 20):

To read:-

```
NSString *html = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElementById('your div id').textContent"];
NSLog(html);
```

To modify:-

```
html = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElementById('your div id').textContent=''"];
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift v3:

```
let doc = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.documentElement.outerHTML")
```

Answer (score 1):

(Xcode 5 iOS 7) Universal App example for iOS 7 and Xcode 5. It is an open source project / example located here: [Link to SimpleWebView (Project Zip and Source Code Example)](https://github.com/matthewferguson/SimpleWebView.git)

Answer (score 1):

you should try this:

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a swift extension like this:

```
extension UIWebView {
    var htmlContent:String? {
        return self.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.documentElement.outerHTML")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift <-> UIWebView**

get HTML from UIWebView`

```
let content = uiWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.body.innerHTML")
```

set HTML into UIWebView

```
//Do not forget to extend a class from `UIWebViewDelegate` and nil the delegate

func someFunction() {
    
    let uiWebView = UIWebView()
    uiWebView.loadHTMLString("<html><body></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
    uiWebView.delegate = self as? UIWebViewDelegate
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    //ready to be processed
}
```

[[Swift <-> WKWebView]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57083024/4770877)