# Getting the HTML source code of a loaded UIWebView

Tags: html, objective-c, uiwebview

How can I get the `HTML` source code of a `UIWebView` and store it in `NSString`?

Comment: what actually you want to ask?

Comment: i have open google.com in my uiwebview and now i want to get html source code of website opened in uiwebview ...   basically i required value of action in <form action="some value">

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992348/reading-html-content-from-a-uiwebview

Comment: there is a difference between two questions, my question was how to read HTML from UIWebView where HTML is preloaded where as other question is reading HTML before loaded into WebView

Answer (score 94):

If you want the source code of an already loaded webview, you can get it like this:

```
    NSString *yourHTMLSourceCodeString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

**Update:** method above works most of the time. But I recently was in a situation where I needed all the code source, not just the body.

Here is a better way:

```
    NSString *yourHTMLSourceCodeString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];
```

(It won't reload the webview).

Comment: +1 for outerHTML. It help me a lot!

Comment: how to load this string in web view again

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that what exactly you need..........but as per your last comment you will get that html data from google like this...

```
     NSData *companyData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
     NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:companyData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    self.yourTextView.text = responseString; // response string contains that data
    [companyData release];
```

Good Luck!

Comment: I suppose the problem here is that using `dataWithContentsOfURL:` requires the web page data to be retrieved again, rather than being extracted from the already loaded UIWebView