# UIWebView Source code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have an *IBAction* on a button with the following code that I am trying to use to retrieve the source code of a UIWebView:

```
- (IBAction)loadInAWebView:(id)sender {
   [self.webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello: %@", _name.text] baseURL:nil];

   NSString *yourHTMLSourceCodeString = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.innerHTML"];

   NSLog(@"%@", yourHTMLSourceCodeString);
}
```

The use of the code above is from the reference I saw at this link: [Getting the HTML source code of a loaded UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167254/getting-the-html-source-code-of-a-loaded-uiwebview).

However, the NSLog function always returns the following:

```
<head></head><body></body>
```

This obviously does not reflect the actual source code of the UIWebView that in my mind should be:

```
<head></head><body>Hello, name</body>
```

Indeed, the UIWebView returns the "Hello, *name*" content but the related source code does not.

How can I edit the code above to retrieve the real UIWebView source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need implement UIWebViewDelegate methods 
 `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`  and set `self.webView.delegate = self;` 
 Put your code `NSString *yourHTMLSourceCodeString = [webView  stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.innerHTML"];` to this method