# Programmatically Add a View to each Page of a UIWebView (iPhone/iPad)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios, uikit

I'm trying to add a View (specifically a UIImageView) to every page of a pagenated UIWebView on iPhone/iPad.  My end goal is to open a PDF and have a signature box at the bottom of every page of the (possibly multipaged) PDF.  I followed [this](http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=132024) tutorial to use a UIImageView as a signature box and [this](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/16552-pdf-viewer-tutorial.html) tutorial to successfully open a PDF in a UIWebView.

My plan was to programmatically get each "page" of a UIWebView and add my signature box at the bottom of each page (stack the views one on top of another).  Is it possible to get each page of a UIWebView? Does cocoa know where each page is or does it do some fancy math calculations to know where to put line breaks?

Ideally, there would be something like:

```
for(UIView *page in webView.pages){
      [self addSignatureBox:page];
 }
```

Comment: UIWebView makes displaying a PDF a piece of cake, but I would suggest looking into CGPDFDocumentRef.  This allows you to grab one page and display it in a View how ever you want.

Comment: Cocoa is the Mac development framework; all UI* classes are specific to Cocoa Touch.

Comment: Yes, but it is also available on the iPhone.  iOS developers are not limited to the UI classes.  I know this because I used CGPDFDocumentRef.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the HTML code for any page in the webview. Check out the following link.

[Reading HTML content from a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992348/reading-html-content-from-a-uiwebview)

Store the HTML code for the webpages in a NSString and modify them to add your signature.

Hope this helps

Comment: Is there a way I can go from the HTML code to inserting cocoa objects (ie, the UIImageView)?  I was thinking I would put the UIImageView over the top of the UIWebView (stack the views).  Should I instead be looking at imbedding the code for the UIImgeView in the actual HTML?

Comment: Its better to add the imageView on top of the webView. Embedding the image in the HTML will be too hectic. Adjust the size of the imageView by the imageView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height) method and add it using the [self.view addSubview:imageView]. To get the pages, get the HTML code as said in the link and load them back into the webview when required.

Comment: Would I be able to tell where the page breaks are merely from the HTML?

Comment: You will have to search the NSString for the page break tags. There are inbuilt methods for searching a substring within a string.