# Why is my UIWebView empty in my unit test?

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, ocunit

I'm putting app-generated content into a `UIWebView`, and trying to test that I'm doing it correctly. Here's the HTML string I'm putting into the web view:

```
@"<html><head></head><body><p>Come, let me clutch thee. I have thee not, and yet I see thee still. Art thou not, fatal vision, sensible to feeling as to sight?</p></body></html>"
```

And it gets into the web view thus:

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString: [self HTMLStringForSnippet: model.body] baseURL: nil];
```

where `model.body` contains just the `<p/>` element, and `-HTMLStringForSnippet:` wraps it into well-formed HTML. In my test, I rely on the answers [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992348/reading-html-content-from-a-uiwebview) to retrieve the HTML content of the body via JavaScript:

```
- (void)testCorrectHTMLLoadedInWebView {
    UIWebView *bodyView = controller.webView;
    NSString *bodyHTML = [bodyView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.innerHTML"];
    STAssertEqualObjects(bodyHTML, model.body, @"Model body should be used for the web view content");
}
```

While I can see by stepping through the code that the `UIWebView` is created correctly and is passed the correct HTML in `-loadHTMLString:baseURL:`, in the test `bodyHTML` is empty. So what do I have to do to see the actual content I expect and previously passed to the web view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It takes a noticeable time for the `UIWebView` to render therefore the problem may be that you access the content before it is fully loaded.

Hook on `UIWebViewDelegate`'s `webViewDidFinishLoad:` method to make sure the content is ready.

Update: 
Maybe [WebViewJavascriptBridge](https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge) will bring some help.

Comment: UiWebView hasn't actually finished rendering when webViewDidFinishLoad: is called, just loading, so a lot of content or expensive content may still cause a problem.

Comment: AFAIK `webViewDidFinishLoad:` is called when `UIWebView` is done loading the input HTML. Sure this doesn't mean all the images/css files/external assets are in place but the question is about accessing the HTML content.

Comment: what would be the correct way to wait for webViewDidFinishLoad in a unittest? It doesn't seem to work with a simple sleep(10).

Comment: @nylund - while(!done && [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]); and set done in webViewDidFinishLoad.

Comment: Now that XCTExpectation is available, that is what should be used. I found that using NSRunLoop works fine locally, but fails intermittently once you push it to Xcode Server. Switching to XCTExpectation seemed to fix this.