# how get website title?

Tags: iphone, webview, nsurlconnection

friends..

Now, I 'm trying to get website title from the url..
To do that , I should get http content first....

I used stringWithContentsOfURL to get http contents according to this following example..
[Reading HTML content from a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992348/reading-html-content-from-a-uiwebview)

When I try "http://www.apple.com" , I got correct results..

But, in case of "http://www.google.co.hk", I  always get nil..

What's the problem in above code?

To get website contents always, how can I do that?

please help me...

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that URL is wrong. Try http://www.google.com.hk instead of http://www.google.co.hk

Comment: Dear,jom

Thanks for your answer..

when I try http: //www.google.co.kr , I also can't get correct result.

how can I solve this?

thanks

Comment: Your url is now right and the page does have title tag? Should work, what is the problem? You are checking for @"document.title" right?