# Allow User to create and view HTML files in Objective C?

Tags: html, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to make an iOS app that allows the user to create an **unlimited** amount of HTML document and save them into the documents folder of the app. This is sort of like a combo question but how can I display a file that is in the documents dictionary.

So my two question are:

How to display HTML file that are in the document dictionary

And

How to allow the user to created unlimited folders and html files

Sorry for the double question...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading HTML content from a UIWebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992348/reading-html-content-from-a-uiwebview)

Comment: What makes you think there's a limit? Obviously there's the physical limit (i.e. storage amount on the iPhone/iPad) but as far as I know there's no arbitrary limitation on the number of documents an application can create.

Comment: What I mean is unlike using NSUserDefaults (were you can create as many saves as you can code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Saving HTML and Other Text Files to the Documents Directory

First, you need to know the path to your documents directory:

```
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

You can create documents and directories there up to the limits of the device storage.  Be aware, however, that only files in the root will show up in iTunes Document Sharing.

So, if you have a string `htmlContent` and a string `htmlFilename`, you can save it.  Do pay attention to the encoding you're using; the encoding in the HTML header and meta tags (if present) should match the encoding used here.

```
NSString *htmlPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:htmlFilename];
[htmlContent writeToFile:htmlPath atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

### Displaying HTML Files Within Your App

You can display HTML in a `UIWebView`.  Assuming you have one called `webView`, you can display any `NSURL` object in it:

```
NSURL *stackOverflowAddress = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"];
[[self webView] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:stackOverflowAddress]];
```

This can include the file you just wrote:

```
NSURL *htmlURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlPath];
[[self webView] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:htmlURL]];
```

Or, you can put a string into it directly:

```
[[self webView] loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:nil];
```

If you use a `UIWebView` for a lot of your functionality, take the time to read the [UIWebViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

### Opening HTML in Safari

It is also possible to tell your application to open URLs elsewhere.  This will usually result in Safari opening.  However, because Safari does not have access to your app's document directory, it cannot display documents while they are saved locally.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:stackoverflowAddress];
```

Comment: Wow, this is the best stack overflow answer I've gotten ever! You get a plus up and accept

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to make an iOS app that allows the user to create an unlimited amount of HTML documents and save them into the documents folder.

HTML files are simply text (as most code-related files are), so of you wish to get it's contents as a string, use NSString's `+stringWithContentsOfFile`.

> How to allow the user to created unlimited folders and html files

As for writing, so long as you write your string with the path extension .html, it will be a perfectly valid HTML file.

EDIT, the path to the documents directory can be found with

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents directory
```

> How to display HTML file that are in the document dictionary

HTML files may be displayed in UIWebViews see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992348/reading-html-content-from-a-uiwebview) for an example.

Comment: That's not exactly what I asked at all.

Comment: How so?   It answers how to put up and save an HTML file.