# How to save html content in document folder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have one URL which I launch in `UIWebView` and save the contents in `Documents` folder when user is online but when user is offline I take the content from document folder and show in `UIWebView`. So can anyone tell how to save html or aspx or jsp etc..contents in `Documents` folder and show in `UIWebView` in offline mode.

Comment: please, check the following thread for the exact solution:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992348/reading-html-content-from-a-uiwebview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992348/reading-html-content-from-a-uiwebview)

Comment: This will help if my page is html what if it is aspx or any other?Will this also work?

Comment: you should know you **cannot** save any server-side contents, I mean source codes of PHP or ASPX or JSP or etc... the webviews (or browsers) always provide a simple text to the client-side because the source-codes are being compiled and ran on the server-side and the server gives us plain text output only. only one thing you can get: the javascripts, because they are client-side contents, and they are being ran by the browsers.

Comment: And I am not able to save images of html page using the methods in above link.

Comment: it is true, you have to download the images one by one using their link and for it you might use the `NSStream` class and I won't mention that you must change the image's links in the saved HTML source for the offline browsing... this is not just a simple HTML content saving as it seems for now.