# my JS fails to get contents of a div in Objective-C

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I am managing to retrieve some text from my Webview. Here is a example of what my HTML file looks like.

`Template.html:`

```
<html>
<body>
        <div id="content" contenteditable="true" style="font-family: Helvetica">
            hello
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

(The code above is exactly all I have in my template.html file.)

Then I run:

```
NSString *js = @"document.getElementById('content').innerHTML";
NSString* html = [panel stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```

It returns NOTHING! Is Xcode stopping to support this type of JS?

Please help, thanks a lot!

---------EDIT------------
For more information, this is how I load my page:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSURL* temp = [bundle URLForResource:@"template" withExtension:@"html"];
[panel loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:temp]];
```

Comment: document.getElementById('content') alone, what does it return?

Comment: I am afraid that it is returning nothing.

Comment: Ok, no surprise then that innerHTML is empty. Any particular reason that the template is missing the html closing tag?

Comment: Check your outlet. I bet `panel` is `nil`.

Comment: @ronnyfm, it is a parsing issue in Stackoverflow, i forgot to give it four space in the front. It is just a very simple example which sadly couldn't get read by another simple JS!@Neal, I checked it, but Panel is returning itself as a Webview

Comment: did you add UIWebview delegates to class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I discovered at last is in fact an issue of UIWebViewDelegate!

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
NSString *js = @"getContent();";//This function is used to get 
                                //the innerHTML of the document.
NSString* html = [panel stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
L22(@"content HTML:",html);
}
```

This will give me the text within my div.

Always make sure the website is fully loaded before extracting any information out of it!:0)

Answer (score 0):

Loaded UIWebView content to be fetch using below line

```
NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

Source:[More - details- stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992348/reading-html-content-from-a-uiwebview)

Thanks

Comment: But I am looking for the specific content inside a DIV though. So far I am very confused because I am using the standard way of fetching data from a Div that I found online. Any suggestions?