# How to fill a HTML form using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I would like to load a web page (containing a form: username and password) in a `UIWebView`, but I would like the web page to be filled when the `UIWebView` is loaded. I read so much stuff and tried so many things, but nothing works.

here is my code :

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://login.live.com"]];

// Specify that it will be a POST request
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

// This is how we set header fields
[request setValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"username" forHTTPHeaderField:@"session[email]"];

// Convert your data and set your request's HTTPBody property
NSString *stringData = @"some data";
NSData *requestBodyData = [stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;

// Create url connection and fire request
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: you need to use some javascript to fill form.

Comment: do you want to show that page on screen(UIWebView) after the page's HTML content loads? I mean do you want to first load HTML content, then load it onto webView?

Comment: after WebViewDid Finish loading.. parse the Html and fill the respected fields you want to fill

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have a form field defined like this:

```
<input type="text" id="mytext">
```

Then you can assign a value to this field as follows:

```
NSString *javascript = @"document.getElementById('mytext').value = 'new value'";
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascript];
```

The above code needs to run after your page has fully loaded. For example, you can make your view controller implement `UIWebViewDelegate`, declare the method `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` and do it there.

Comment: I also have to click on a button in the web page via the objective c, can i use the same kind of process?

Comment: Yes, you can use the code above as an example on how to run any JavaScript from within your app. Obviously you set fill multiple form values :)

Answer (score -2):

**EDITED:** 20/03/2014 -: I added how to get the code from the `UIWebView`

If you want know when the page did finish loading, you should implement `UIWebViewDelegate` in your `UIViewController`:

Then you can detect when the page finish loading by implementing this method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    [_activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    _activityIndicator.hidden = TRUE;
}
```

In you case, you want to modify the code when the page it's loaded, so in the method `(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` you should do the next to get the code as a `NSString`:

```
NSURL *requestURL = [[yourWebView request] URL];
NSError *error;
NSString *page = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:requestURL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
```

For more details take a look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/992367/2835520).

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my question is really about modifying the web page...

Comment: Yes, this answer refers to the second question: _...in a UIWebView. **But I would like the webpage to be filled when the UIWebView is loaded…** I read so much stuff..._. If i find something about the first question, will post you the answer.

Comment: This's useful to know when the page is ready to can modify the code, if you try to modify it before finish loading, then there's no html code to modify.

Comment: This has absolutely no relevance to this question and doesn't answer it in anyway, my -1 remains.

Comment: Sorry then, I think i am not understanding the question dues to my low english level.