# UIWebview within UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

I have a custom cell that contains a web view - the thing is I would like to only call the request to load a URL once for the web view. Right now I loading the request within cellForRowAtIndex: and of course this is making the request called many times. How do I make sure the request is made only once and what is the most optimal way to do this?

Comment: request made only once or request made when the cell is visible to user ?

Comment: Or you can have a bool flag and set it to NO, after the first time in the cell for rowat index method.

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining a data-structure to store the responses from the web-request will solve this scenario. say for `indexpath` first time you look up in the data structure (`NSMutableArray` would be more appropriately), as you are looking for the data for the first time, you wont find any, then fetch the response & store it into the data-structure. Then second time when the cell at the same `indexpath` you lookup in the data-structure, voila this time you don't have to make the request.

For simplicity i'm using `NSMutableDictionary` named `responseData`

1. initiate it inside the `viewDidLoad`
2. in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

   ```
   UITableViewCell *cell = //deque the cell

   NSString *responseKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%d,%d", indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

   NSString *htmlData = responseData[responseKey];

   if(htmlData == nil)
   {
       htmlData = //whatever the way do your request, put the response in the htmlData. as you are doing asynchronous loading of the web-request, set the cell's webView in the completion. NB:: do gui related work on gui/main thread.

       responseData[responseKey] = htmlData;
   }

   //set the htmlData to your, cell's webView
   ```

Comment: for help in html content & `UIWebView` can have a look in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992348/reading-html-content-from-a-uiwebview)