# iOS/iPhone insert formatted text from wysiwyg

Tags: html, ios, iphone, wysiwyg, markup

Can iOS/iPhone devs insert html from wysiwyg editor into the app?

I remember, that Android had some Webview, but not sure that it can accept raw html as input.

What ways there are to insert text with markup?

Formatted text comes from api as json.

Comment: Yes you can load raw html in UIWEBVIEW

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992348/reading-html-content-from-a-uiwebview view this link

Comment: And you can inject there own html, into the blank page?

Comment: I am not getting what you actually want ?