# Download PDF via UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` that loads a PDF using Basic Auth like so

```
NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:_urlString];
NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", usr, pwd];
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding76CharacterLineLength]];
NSMutableURLRequest *mutableRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[mutableRequest setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[_webView loadRequest:mutableRequest];
```

Is there a way for me to easily save this PDF file onto disk? I've tried this but failed:

```
NSData *fileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:_webView.request.URL];
```

My URL looks like this: `www.domain.com/files/foo.pdf`

Comment: `initWithContentsOfURL:` method of `NSData` does a simple GET, but you needed to set tom Auth params that's why it fails.
What about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992348/reading-html-content-from-a-uiwebview to retrieve the content (already downloaded) from the UIWebView, and then save it?

Comment: I tried evaluating the javascript in webViewDidFinishLoad but it returns an empty string. Probably because I'm only having UIWebView load a PDF, not any actual HTML markup.

Comment: Try `[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:mutableRequest completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) { if (data) { //SaveDataIntoDisk + dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){ [_webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"application/pdf"  textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil]; }); } }] resume];`?

Comment: @Larme This works perfectly. If you want to write up an answer, I'll accept it. For future readers, I'll include what I ended up doing in an EDIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-initWithContentsOfURL:` method of `NSData` does a simple HTTP GET, but you needed to set some Authorization params that's why it fails.

To avoid downloading twice the data, you could use `NSURLSession` to download it, save it, and use the `-loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:` of `UIWebView` to load it.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *mutableRequest = //Your Custom request with URL and Headers
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:mutableRequest completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) 
{
    if (data) 
    { 
        //SaveDataIntoDisk
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){ 
            [_webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil]; 
        }); 
    } 
}] resume];
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift :

```
        let webView = UIWebView()
        let url = URL(string: "")!
        let urlRequest : URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest , completionHandler: { (data, urlResponse, error) in

            if (data != nil){
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    webView.load(data!, mimeType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: url)
                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Approach:- You can download the PDF file Data and save it in Temp Directory or Your Prefered Directory. then use that saved directory to open the file in WebView.

```
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                    guard let data = data, error == nil else {

                        return
                    }
//MARK:- Now Saving the Document Data into Directory. I am using the temp directory you can change it to yours.
                    let tempDirectory = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
                    self.tmpURL = tempDirectory.appendingPathComponent(response?.suggestedFilename ?? "fileName.png")

                     do {
                        try data.write(to: self.tmpURL! )
                     } catch {
                        print(error)
                     }
                     DispatchQueue.main.async {
 //MARK:- Instead of using MIME type and NSData .now you can use the file directory to open the file in WEBView
                         self.webView.loadFileURL(self.tmpURL!, allowingReadAccessTo: self.tmpURL!)     
                      }
                }
```