# how to show only a part of webpage by using webview

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I would like to use WKWebView to show the webpage which is the road condition in Iceland. I using the following code, but it will show the whole webpage.

```
  @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let url = URL(string: "http://www.road.is/travel-info/road-conditions-and-weather/entire-iceland-road-conditions-map/"){
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }
}
```

I only want to show the picture below:
[image]

because this is not only a static picture, this includes javascript and jquery.  I can not just download it as a picture and show by using image view.

how can I only load this interactive picture by using webview?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may have to parse html to find.

see this question/answer [Reading HTML content from a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992348/reading-html-content-from-a-uiwebview#992367)

Inspecting the webpage I found the image link:
http://www.vegagerdin.is/vgdata/faerd/faerdarkort/sudurland.png