# Unable to get HTML string from UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I loaded a file on uiWebView. Its extension type is ".pages". Now I trying to get HTML string from webview, but it returns to empty string.
For ".doc or .docx" files getting the String. It happens to ".pages" extension only.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];
```

Refer this post - [Reading HTML content from a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992348/reading-html-content-from-a-uiwebview)